# WPF DropShadowEffect on a transparent object

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to be able to see a drop shadow, but not the object that is creating the drop shadow.

The code below will only work if I give the ellipse a fill colour.

```
<Ellipse Width="640" Height="640">
    <Ellipse.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Color="Cyan" BlurRadius="60"  />
    </Ellipse.Effect>
</Ellipse>
```

This makes sence as an invisible object wouldn't have a shadow. But, what if I really wanted it to? Is there a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Are you looking for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295589/how-to-draw-a-drop-shadow-on-a-transparent-rectangle) Or are you expecting the entire shadow to appear? If later, did you try making the ellipse transparent by setting the alpha value to zero?

Comment: I was looking for something similar to the link. I was partly just exploring different ways to get certain effects. I thought drop shadows would be a nice easy way to create more complex effects, but it looks like it is more difficult than that and not really worth the effort. Thanks for your help.